# Detecting if type is a function

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<class T>
struct IsFunc
{
    typedef char one;
    typedef struct 
    {
        char dummy_[2];
    } two;

    static one f(...);

    static two f(T (*)[1]);
    enum {value = (sizeof(f<T>(0)) == 1)};
};
```

And if I try to run it in main:

```
void functionA();
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        int a = 0;
        cout << IsFunc<functionA>::value;//<=--------HERE

        return 0;
    }
```

I'm getting an error:
**Error 1   error C2923: 'IsFunc' : 'functionA' is not a valid template type**
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`functionA` is a function, not a type, so it cannot be a valid template parameter to `IsFunc` which expects a type.

If you need a template to detect whether a type is a function type, there is already [`boost::is_function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_function.html) (which is part of TR1/C++0x).

Comment: IsFunc<void()> on the other hand, is fine :)

Comment: @Armen : Thats because `void()` is a type id. The Standard says `A template-argument for a template-parameter which is a type shall be a type-id.`

Comment: @Kenny && Armen so is there a way to check if identyfier is a function?

Comment: @There: Yes, boost::is_function

Comment: @There: You need something like `decltype` (C++0x) or Boost.TypeOf (not very portable) to convert an identifier to a type.

Comment: @KennyTM but AFAIC Boost couldn't use themself to implement it so they had to use just plain "standard" C++ am I right? And if yes how is it done?

Comment: @There: Boost.TypeOf depends on non-standard C++ feature, like g++'s `typeof`, otherwise it can only recognize a finite category of types. Fortunately function types can be detected by Boost.Typeof on compliant compilers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `template<class T> class X;` you don't expect `X<3>` to work and deduce that `T` is `int`, do you? The same is here `IsFunc<FunctionA>` is invalid, but `IsFunc<void()>` is fine. HTH

Comment: @Armen yes, you're absolutely right, although it would be nice if it would work that way, why not?

Comment: @There: It would be nice if the program semantics were deduced by the compiler from the comments, don't you think? :)))))

Comment: @Armen well I think what I've said isn't that silly and illogical, is it?

Comment: @There: Sorry, I didn't want to offend you or somehow imply that your question is silly. But there are just soooo many things in C++ that it would be nice to have and that are far easier to implement that this particular one is definitely not in the priority list. anyway if you have a metafunction taking a type, you can easily convert it into a funtion - template<class Type> bool func(Type value) {return Metafunction<Type>::value;}

Comment: @Armen is there an un/official site that I would be able to check "wish list" with features for C++?

Comment: @There: Yeah, there is - http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/standards, and it's official. Also post this kind of things in comp.lang.c++.moderated newsgroup, because many standards committee members read that newsgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Others already stated the reason but would this help you?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>
namespace
{
   template<typename T>
   bool test_if_function (T const &v)
   {
      return std::tr1::is_function<T>::value;
   }

   void functionA()
   {
   }
}

int main()
{
   printf ("%d\r\n", test_if_function (1));
   printf ("%d\r\n", test_if_function (functionA));

   return 0;
}
```